# Update Checkmark state via REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, angularjs

I'm currently building a SharePoint Hosted App which gets any task list items from various sites and pushes them into an array. I'm using AngularJS to make these requests. Running a GET request on a task item returns the property 'Checkmark' which strangely is a string ("0" = Unchecked, "1" = Checked), I'm able to use this to get all unchecked items.

The difficulty is when the user clicks the checkbox on the app, I want to then update the checkmark property for the item. The HTTP POST request is as follows:

```
var checkedData = JSON.stringify({ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" }, "Checkmark": task.Checkmark.toString() });
$http.post(url, checkedData, {
    headers: {
        'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'X-RequestDigest': requestDigest,
        'IF-MATCH': '*'
    }
})
```

However this doesn't update the checkmark property. If I change "Checked" to "Title" in the POST body then the Title changes, so the call is definitely working, I just can't seem to update the checked property.

Comment: task.Checkmark returns either 0 or 1 as an integer, which results in the following error: "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.String'. See the inner exception for more details." Adding .toString() silences any errors but doesn't update the item. Using a true/false bool also returns the same error.

Comment: It doesn't error but doesn't update the field either. I'm starting to think it might be read-only.

Comment: `Checkmark` is not acustom field?

Comment: There aren't any custom fields on the lists, if I do a GET request on Lists(<guid>)/items then all the items return a Checkmark field. This seems to change based on whether the item is checked in SharePoint or not, I can't seem to change it programatically though.

Comment: Ah! PercentComplete seems to do the trick. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Checkmark` is a read-only field. Try changing `PercentComplete` to 100

[image]

Comment: I've set PercentComplete to 100 and that automatically changes Checkmark to "1" and the status to completed, so this works perfectly, thanks!